# ASP.NET MVC5 namespace Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I've been developing quite a complex web app for the company I am working for, and I have a problem with routing in asp.net mvc.

I know about the areas, but I don't want to use this approach.

Url structure I have now:
`Default`
`Administration_Users/*`
`Administration_UserGroups/*`
`Configuration_Report/*`
`Configuration_Schematics/*`
`Dictionaries_DeviceCatalogue/*`
`Dictionaries_DeviceParameters/*`

... and so on. (* means multiple methods inside, like Index, Edit, etc.)

Url structure I want:
`Default`
`Administration/Users/*`
`Administration/UserGroups/*`
`Configuration/Report/*`
`Configuration/Schematics/*`
`Dictionaries/DeviceCatalogue/*`
`Dictionaries/DeviceParameters/*`

I **CAN** use areas, but the problem is that these will later expand, as it is just one part of the web app. So, they will look like more this:

`EquipmentManager/Configuration/Report/*`
`EquipmentManager/Configuration/Schematics/*`
`EquipmentManager/Dictionaries/DeviceCatalogue/*`
`EquipmentManager/Dictionaries/DeviceParameters/*`

So, my question is: Is there a working namespace approach instead of area one?
Basically, I want `InternalWebApp.Controllers.EquipmentManager.Configuration.Report` controller that is located in corresponding folder map to views which are located in `InternalWebApp/Views/EquipmentManager/Configuration/Report` folder of my solution without having to map every controller manually in RouteConfig.cs.

Comment: Have a look at [MvcCodeRouting](https://github.com/maxtoroq/MvcCodeRouting), which is a hierarchial alternative to areas.

Comment: @NightOwl888 thank you. This is pretty much what I wanted. Everyone who is interested in this approach should look into a mvc5 branch of this repository.